# hyperlink click to load new page an execute javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have two pages, `a.html` and `b.html`.

In b.html there are two buttons `b1` and `b2` which on clicking run javascript function `pop()` with parameters passed as `b1` and `b2` respectively. Now running pop changes the contents of my `b.html` depending on the button clicked.

Now I have two hyperlinks `a1` and `a2` in `a.html`.
What I want to achieve here is, if I click `a1` I want `b.html` to be loaded and the contents to be displayed as it would have been after clicking `b1`.

So basically when I click `a1` in `a.html`, I want `b.html` to be loaded and then `pop()` to be executed with `b1` as parameter and the resulting page displayed. Can it be done?

Comment: some more code would be usefull

Comment: are you using any server scriptiong?

Comment: no this is entirely javascript and html. thats the reason i didnt mention any code.

Comment: Please refrain from adding `code formatting` to `random` parts of your `question`.  Code formatting is designed for small snippets of code, variable names, and other things that should be marked as code.  It is not a formatting tool and using it for emphasis is *silly*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it through URL parameters, such as a.html?value=test.

On `a.html`, clicking the button takes you to `b.html?dopop=true`.

You can then implement some Javascript on the page load (`$(document).load(function() {});`, & there's plenty of jQuery plugins to handle the parameters) to check if dopop is specified or true.  If it is, execute that function.

Answer (score -2):

You could do something like this, if you are using jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
var content = $("div#content");

$("a#1").click(function(){
   content.load("a.html");
});

$("a#2").click(function(){
   content.load("b.html");
});

});
</script>

<a id="1" href="#">Click A</a>
<a id="2" href="#">Click B</a>

<div id="content"></div>
```

More information about jQuery load can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/load/